# In the definition of sequences diverging to infinity, why must the constants be positive?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We are given the following definitions

1. A sequence $(a_n)$ diverges to $\infty$ if  for each $ M \in \mathbb{R}^+ \exists N_M \in \mathbb{N} \  \text{such that } \\ a_n > M \ \forall n \geq N_M$
2. A sequence $(a_n)$ diverges to $- \infty$ if for each $m \in \mathbb{R}^+ \exists N_m \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{such that} \\ a_n < m \ \forall n\geq N_m$

I understand what the definition implies, the only thing that I do not feel certain about, is why must M and m be greater than zero?

EDIT:
Here is the exact extract from my notes

> **3.3.8 $\quad$ Definition**  
>   
>  **(a)** $\quad$ A sequence $(a_n)$ **diverges** to $\infty$ (Write: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$) 
>  if for each real number $M\gt0$ there exists a $N_M\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n\gt M$ for all $n\geqslant N_M$. 
>  
> **(b)** $\quad$  sequence $(a_n)$ **diverges** to $-\infty$ (Write: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$) 
>  if for each real number $m\gt0$ there exists a $N_m\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n\lt m$ for all $n\geqslant N_m$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm typing this on my phone :). So I did not have a preview of what it looks like - so I could only see the result after I posted :)

Comment: Isn't it $-m$ in the second (new) item?

Comment: I just edited in a picture of the definition in my notes :)

Comment: Then there is a typo in your notes :) (the identically zero sequence $a_n=0 \forall n$ satisfies **(b)**, yet is far from diverging to $-\infty$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this definition means is that a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ diverges to $\infty$ if, and only if, for any "threshold" $M$ of your choosing, after a while* all the elements of the sequence are above the threshold**. That is, no matter how high a threshold you fix, the sequence will eventually reach it, and stay above it afterwards.

The choice $M\geq 0$ is completely arbitrary: the definition remains exactly the same if you allow $M\in\mathbb{R}$ (if you choose a threshold $M < 0$, then you can take $N_M=N_0$).

*a while: $\exists N_M$

** $\forall n\geq N_M$, $a_n \geq M$

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense! That's exactly what was bugging me about it - I simply could not see why (according to our definition) it "HAS" to be greater than zero...